# CXF response validation fails with SOAPUI

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, cxf

We are creating CXF SOAP contract-first web services.
For that, we build our xsd, then use XJC to generate the java classes.
We then create an interface for our endpoint and its implementation.
In the spring file, we declare our endpoint, we activate the validation and set the shemaLocation.
If we test the web service with SOAPUI (and activate the validation of both request and response in SOAPUI), we get a validation error on the response

> "line 4: Expected element 'responses@...' instead of 'readItemsResponse@...' here in element readItemsResponse@..."

There is no error on the server side.
If we turn off the response validation of SOAPUI, everything works fine.
How is it possible to get this kind of error even though everything is done according to the xsd.

Spring declaration extract :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
default-dependency-check="none" default-lazy-init="false">

<bean id="logInbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
<bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logInbound"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
    </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="logInbound"/>
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
</cxf:bus> 

<jaxws:endpoint id="gen.kernel.ItemSOA" implementor="fr.vif.vif5_7.gen.item.soa.endpoint.item.ItemEndPoint"
    address="/gen/kernel/ItemSOA">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
    <jaxws:schemaLocations>
        <jaxws:schemaLocation>classpath:/gen/item/soa/schemas/item/ItemSOA.xsd</jaxws:schemaLocation>
    </jaxws:schemaLocations>
</jaxws:endpoint>

<bean id="SoaitemPPO" class="fr.vif.vif5_7.gen.item.soa.endpoint.item.proxy.SoaitemPPO" />
```

SOAP message sent :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ker="http://www.vif.fr/vif5_7/gen/kernel">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <ker:readItems>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ker:readItemsRequest>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ker:generalInfos>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ker:consumerId>?</ker:consumerId>
            </ker:generalInfos>
            <ker:itemSelection>
               <ker:company>OM</ker:company>
               <ker:establishment>01</ker:establishment>
               <ker:itemSelection>
                  <ker:item>CREPE</ker:item>
                </ker:itemSelection>
            </ker:itemSelection>
         </ker:readItemsRequest>
       </ker:readItems>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP message received :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <ns1:readItemsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://www.vif.fr/vif5_7/gen/kernel">
     <ns1:readItemsResponse>
        <ns1:responses>
           <ns1:response>
              <ns1:codeItem>CREPE</ns1:codeItem>
              <ns1:standardResponses>
                 <ns1:standardResponse>
                    <ns1:status>OK</ns1:status>
                    <ns1:message>Item : CREPE - crepe hb</ns1:message>
                 </ns1:standardResponse>
              </ns1:standardResponses>
           </ns1:response>
        </ns1:responses>
        <ns1:items>
           <ns1:item>
              <ns1:company>OM</ns1:company>
              <ns1:etablishment>01</ns1:etablishment>
              <ns1:codeItem>CREPE</ns1:codeItem>
              <ns1:itemMandatoryInfo>
                 <ns1:itemDesignation>crepe hb</ns1:itemDesignation>
                 <ns1:itemShortDesign>crepe</ns1:itemShortDesign>
                 <ns1:codeBasicFam>SF</ns1:codeBasicFam>
                 <ns1:codeAccountingFam>01</ns1:codeAccountingFam>
                 <ns1:itemType>Goods</ns1:itemType>
              </ns1:itemMandatoryInfo>
              <ns1:itemUnit>
                 <ns1:firstUnit>P</ns1:firstUnit>
                 <ns1:secondUnit>Kg</ns1:secondUnit>
                 <ns1:firstUnitCoef>1.0</ns1:firstUnitCoef>
                 <ns1:secondUnitCoef>0.5</ns1:secondUnitCoef>
                 <ns1:isConstantQuantity>false</ns1:isConstantQuantity>
                 <ns1:codeEnteredFirstUnit>P</ns1:codeEnteredFirstUnit>
              </ns1:itemUnit>
              <ns1:itemGeneralInfo>
                 <ns1:otherId1>00000</ns1:otherId1>
                 <ns1:isMiscItem>false</ns1:isMiscItem>
                 <ns1:tare>
                    <ns1:qty>0.1</ns1:qty>
                    <ns1:unit>Kg</ns1:unit>
                 </ns1:tare>
                 <ns1:eanData>
                    <ns1:eanType>DUN14</ns1:eanType>
                    <ns1:ean>106789014</ns1:ean>
                    <ns1:guideWeight>21</ns1:guideWeight>
                    <ns1:guidePrice>02</ns1:guidePrice>
                    <ns1:codeRetailUnit>CAR</ns1:codeRetailUnit>
                    <ns1:nbOUT>1</ns1:nbOUT>
                    <ns1:nbINNER>1</ns1:nbINNER>
                    <ns1:nbOU>1</ns1:nbOU>
                    <ns1:nbLayers>2</ns1:nbLayers>
                    <ns1:eanLevel>Consumer unit</ns1:eanLevel>
                 </ns1:eanData>
                 <ns1:validityPeriod>
                    <ns1:dateStart>2004-10-25T00:00:00.000+02:00</ns1:dateStart>
                    <ns1:dateEnd>2999-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:dateEnd>
                 </ns1:validityPeriod>
              </ns1:itemGeneralInfo>
              <ns1:heldInStockData>
                 <ns1:isFirstUnitIsStock>true</ns1:isFirstUnitIsStock>
                 <ns1:isSecondUnitIsStock>true</ns1:isSecondUnitIsStock>
                 <ns1:isHeldByBatch>true</ns1:isHeldByBatch>
                 <ns1:isReserved>false</ns1:isReserved>
                 <ns1:codeRawMaterialDepot>GEN</ns1:codeRawMaterialDepot>
                 <ns1:codeRawMaterialLocation/>
                 <ns1:picking>FIFO</ns1:picking>
                 <ns1:codeInventoryFrequency>Free</ns1:codeInventoryFrequency>
                 <ns1:costType>$LOT</ns1:costType>
                 <ns1:codeStockCostingUnit>Kg</ns1:codeStockCostingUnit>
                 <ns1:isAllocatedAutomatically>false</ns1:isAllocatedAutomatically>
                 <ns1:batchType>Mono item</ns1:batchType>
                 <ns1:codeRefItem>CREPE</ns1:codeRefItem>
                 <ns1:nbStorage>10.0</ns1:nbStorage>
                 <ns1:nbOptimalStorage>90.0</ns1:nbOptimalStorage>
                 <ns1:NbDaysGuaranteedReceipt>0.0</ns1:NbDaysGuaranteedReceipt>
                 <ns1:NbDaysGuaranteedShipping>0.0</ns1:NbDaysGuaranteedShipping>
                 <ns1:MaxAgeReceipt>0.0</ns1:MaxAgeReceipt>
                 <ns1:StockCheckingUnit>Kg</ns1:StockCheckingUnit>
                 <ns1:qualityData>
                    <ns1:lockStatus>B01</ns1:lockStatus>
                    <ns1:useStatus>D01</ns1:useStatus>
                    <ns1:outsideLimitStatus>P01</ns1:outsideLimitStatus>
                    <ns1:lockingDuration>0.0</ns1:lockingDuration>
                    <ns1:useDuration>30.0</ns1:useDuration>
                    <ns1:manualUnlocking>false</ns1:manualUnlocking>
                 </ns1:qualityData>
                 <ns1:replenishmentUnit>Kg</ns1:replenishmentUnit>
                 <ns1:safetyStock>60000.0</ns1:safetyStock>
                 <ns1:maxStock>0.0</ns1:maxStock>
                 <ns1:coverage>0.0</ns1:coverage>
              </ns1:heldInStockData>
              <ns1:soldItemData>
                 <ns1:itemSalesDesignation>crepe</ns1:itemSalesDesignation>
                 <ns1:preferedOrderUnit>P</ns1:preferedOrderUnit>
                 <ns1:preferedPriceUnit>P</ns1:preferedPriceUnit>
                 <ns1:isRPManagement>false</ns1:isRPManagement>
                 <ns1:salesPeriod>
                    <ns1:dateStart>2004-10-25T00:00:00.000+02:00</ns1:dateStart>
                    <ns1:dateEnd>2999-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:dateEnd>
                 </ns1:salesPeriod>
                 <ns1:codeSalesModel>Normal</ns1:codeSalesModel>
                 <ns1:isFree>false</ns1:isFree>
                 <ns1:codePriceItem>CREPE</ns1:codePriceItem>
                 <ns1:isCompound>false</ns1:isCompound>
                 <ns1:isRPCompound>true</ns1:isRPCompound>
                 <ns1:criterionUBDorBBD/>
                 <ns1:typeUBDorBBD>UBD</ns1:typeUBDorBBD>
                 <ns1:prepaPeriod>0</ns1:prepaPeriod>
                 <ns1:prepaPeriodTime>0</ns1:prepaPeriodTime>
                 <ns1:preparationShippingAreas>
                    <ns1:prepaShippingArea>
                       <ns1:codePreparationWorkshop>01</ns1:codePreparationWorkshop>
                       <ns1:codeShippingArea>01</ns1:codeShippingArea>
                       <ns1:shippingDepot>EXP</ns1:shippingDepot>
                       <ns1:returnDepot>EXP</ns1:returnDepot>
                       <ns1:isPreferredArea>true</ns1:isPreferredArea>
                    </ns1:prepaShippingArea>
                 </ns1:preparationShippingAreas>
              </ns1:soldItemData>
              <ns1:purchasesData>
                 <ns1:isReceivedInWorkshop>false</ns1:isReceivedInWorkshop>
                 <ns1:purchasePeriod>
                    <ns1:dateStart>2005-10-25T00:00:00.000+02:00</ns1:dateStart>
                    <ns1:dateEnd>2012-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:dateEnd>
                 </ns1:purchasePeriod>
                 <ns1:receiptAreas>
                    <ns1:receiptArea>
                       <ns1:codeArea/>
                       <ns1:codeEndDepot>GEN</ns1:codeEndDepot>
                       <ns1:codeEndLocation/>
                       <ns1:isPreferredArea>true</ns1:isPreferredArea>
                    </ns1:receiptArea>
                    <ns1:receiptArea>
                       <ns1:codeArea>E01</ns1:codeArea>
                       <ns1:codeEndDepot>GE2</ns1:codeEndDepot>
                       <ns1:codeEndLocation>A1</ns1:codeEndLocation>
                       <ns1:isPreferredArea>false</ns1:isPreferredArea>
                    </ns1:receiptArea>
                 </ns1:receiptAreas>
              </ns1:purchasesData>
              <ns1:manufacturingData>
                 <ns1:isGenericValue>false</ns1:isGenericValue>
                 <ns1:codeWorkshopInputProfile/>
                 <ns1:codeWorkshopOutputProfile/>
                 <ns1:codeProdInputProfile/>
                 <ns1:codeProdOutputProfile/>
                 <ns1:shrinkageRate>0.0</ns1:shrinkageRate>
                 <ns1:ManufacturingToBeCosted>false</ns1:ManufacturingToBeCosted>
                 <ns1:purchasedItem>
                    <ns1:leadTime>0.0</ns1:leadTime>
                    <ns1:buyReplenishmentRule>Batch for batch</ns1:buyReplenishmentRule>
                    <ns1:orderPoint>0.0</ns1:orderPoint>
                    <ns1:minBuy>0.0</ns1:minBuy>
                    <ns1:multipleBuy>0.0</ns1:multipleBuy>
                 </ns1:purchasedItem>
                 <ns1:manufacturedItem>
                    <ns1:itemInput>CREPE</ns1:itemInput>
                    <ns1:itemOutput>CREPE</ns1:itemOutput>
                    <ns1:startType>Pull</ns1:startType>
                    <ns1:moDesignationRule>F01</ns1:moDesignationRule>
                    <ns1:replenishentRule>Batch for batch</ns1:replenishentRule>
                    <ns1:minReplenishment>0.0</ns1:minReplenishment>
                    <ns1:multipleReplenishment>0.0</ns1:multipleReplenishment>
                    <ns1:maxReplenishment>0.0</ns1:maxReplenishment>
                 </ns1:manufacturedItem>
              </ns1:manufacturingData>
              <ns1:preparationData>
                 <ns1:itemComposition>OM</ns1:itemComposition>
                 <ns1:groupRPCharacteristic>Fixed weight</ns1:groupRPCharacteristic>
                 <ns1:preparationType>By transformation of product</ns1:preparationType>
                 <ns1:preparationProfil>$000002001</ns1:preparationProfil>
                 <ns1:codeItemToPrepare>CREPE</ns1:codeItemToPrepare>
                 <ns1:codePreparationUnit>P</ns1:codePreparationUnit>
              </ns1:preparationData>
              <ns1:downgradedItems>
                 <ns1:codeDowngradedItem>CREPE2</ns1:codeDowngradedItem>
              </ns1:downgradedItems>
              <ns1:companyDescCriteria>
                 <ns1:criterion>
                    <ns1:criterionCode>$ORIGINE</ns1:criterionCode>
                    <ns1:stringValue>
                       <ns1:stringValueUnique/>
                    </ns1:stringValue>
                 </ns1:criterion>
                 <ns1:criterion>
                    <ns1:criterionCode>EAN-UVC</ns1:criterionCode>
                    <ns1:stringValue>
                       <ns1:stringValueUnique>123</ns1:stringValueUnique>
                    </ns1:stringValue>
                 </ns1:criterion>
              </ns1:companyDescCriteria>
              <ns1:establishmentDescCriteria>
                 <ns1:criterion>
                    <ns1:criterionCode>$ARTGEN</ns1:criterionCode>
                    <ns1:stringValue>
                       <ns1:stringValueUnique/>
                    </ns1:stringValue>
                 </ns1:criterion>
                 <ns1:criterion>
                    <ns1:criterionCode>$TOLFAB</ns1:criterionCode>
                    <ns1:doubleValue>
                       <ns1:doubleValueBound>
                          <ns1:doubleValueMin>10.0</ns1:doubleValueMin>
                          <ns1:doubleValueMax>15.0</ns1:doubleValueMax>
                       </ns1:doubleValueBound>
                    </ns1:doubleValue>
                 </ns1:criterion>
                 <ns1:criterion>
                    <ns1:criterionCode>PATE</ns1:criterionCode>
                    <ns1:stringValue>
                       <ns1:stringValueUnique/>
                    </ns1:stringValue>
                 </ns1:criterion>
              </ns1:establishmentDescCriteria>
              <ns1:allergens>
                 <ns1:allergen>
                    <ns1:criterionData>
                       <ns1:criterionCode>$ALCELER</ns1:criterionCode>
                       <ns1:stringValue>
                          <ns1:stringValueUnique>N/A</ns1:stringValueUnique>
                       </ns1:stringValue>
                    </ns1:criterionData>
                    <ns1:locked>false</ns1:locked>
                    <ns1:reason/>
                 </ns1:allergen>
                 <ns1:allergen>
                    <ns1:criterionData>
                       <ns1:criterionCode>$ALLAIT</ns1:criterionCode>
                       <ns1:stringValue>
                          <ns1:stringValueUnique>N/A</ns1:stringValueUnique>
                       </ns1:stringValue>
                    </ns1:criterionData>
                    <ns1:locked>false</ns1:locked>
                    <ns1:reason/>
                 </ns1:allergen>
              </ns1:allergens>
              <ns1:hierarchies>
                 <ns1:hierarchy>
                    <ns1:codeHierarchy>CREPE</ns1:codeHierarchy>
                    <ns1:codeHierarchyValue>SF</ns1:codeHierarchyValue>
                 </ns1:hierarchy>
                 <ns1:hierarchy>
                    <ns1:codeHierarchy>CREPEDD</ns1:codeHierarchy>
                    <ns1:codeHierarchyValue>01</ns1:codeHierarchyValue>
                 </ns1:hierarchy>
                 <ns1:hierarchy>
                    <ns1:codeHierarchy>SAFE</ns1:codeHierarchy>
                    <ns1:codeHierarchyValue>CREPE</ns1:codeHierarchyValue>
                 </ns1:hierarchy>
                 <ns1:hierarchy>
                    <ns1:codeHierarchy>TACTILE</ns1:codeHierarchy>
                    <ns1:codeHierarchyValue>OM</ns1:codeHierarchyValue>
                 </ns1:hierarchy>
              </ns1:hierarchies>
              <ns1:otherUnits>
                 <ns1:unit>
                    <ns1:codeUnit>K</ns1:codeUnit>
                    <ns1:codeRefUnit>Kg</ns1:codeRefUnit>
                    <ns1:isConstantQuantity>false</ns1:isConstantQuantity>
                    <ns1:positiveDiff>0.0</ns1:positiveDiff>
                    <ns1:negativeDiff>0.0</ns1:negativeDiff>
                    <ns1:unitCoef>1.0</ns1:unitCoef>
                    <ns1:refUnitCoef>0.8</ns1:refUnitCoef>
                 </ns1:unit>
                 <ns1:unit>
                    <ns1:codeUnit>L</ns1:codeUnit>
                    <ns1:codeRefUnit>P</ns1:codeRefUnit>
                    <ns1:isConstantQuantity>false</ns1:isConstantQuantity>
                    <ns1:positiveDiff>0.0</ns1:positiveDiff>
                    <ns1:negativeDiff>0.0</ns1:negativeDiff>
                    <ns1:unitCoef>1.0</ns1:unitCoef>
                    <ns1:refUnitCoef>4.0</ns1:refUnitCoef>
                 </ns1:unit>
              </ns1:otherUnits>
           </ns1:item>
        </ns1:items>
     </ns1:readItemsResponse>
  </ns1:readItemsResponse>
```

The CXF version used is : 2.7.7

Any help would be appreciated.

The problem happens when I specify a targetNamespace for my endpoint interface. If I remove this information, I don't have the validation problem anymore. As I don't want to use the package name as a targetNamespace, I need to add this information.

Comment: If you check your response you can check readItemResponse is coming twice is it your expectation? I guess both your input and output would not work........ can you check by input by printing some of the values?

Comment: Try having Bare binding  @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle =SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)

Comment: I noticed that the readItemResponse is coming twice and I don't know why.

Comment: In fact, I noticed that the readItemResponse is coming twice and I don't know why. My input is OK, it is only the output that is wrong (which is really strange). By the way, the content under the 2 readItemResponse elements is the expected result). I tried the @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle =SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE) annotation, without any success (I get marshalling errors when requesting the web service with SOAPUI).

Comment: Can you add your xsd?

Comment: Don't post huge files as answers to your question. If you can't find the parts of the file that are relevant to your question, consider posting it to [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com) or a similar service.

Comment: OK sorry for that. The content of the xsd can be found at that address http://pastebin.com/kkhycPLX